# Bash : How to insert a block of text after a certain line into a file in Unix?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have a file file1.txt like below :

```
line 1 file 1
line 2 file 1
line 3 file 1
line 4 file 1
```

And a second file file2.txt like below :

```
line 1 file 2
line 2 file 2
line 3 file 2
line 4 file 2
line 5 file 2
```

I want to right a one line command (preferably with sed ) that will get the lines 2-4 from second file (file2.txt) and add those lines after line 3 into the first file(file1.txt) .

So my output should be like below :

```
line 1 file 1
line 2 file 1
line 3 file 1
line 2 file 2
line 3 file 2
line 4 file 2
line 4 file 1
```

For getting the lines 2-4 from second file i could use :

```
sed -n '2,4p' file2.txt
```

And for inserting the lines after line 3 in file 1 i could use like below :

```
sed '4i<What to insert here>' file1.txt
```

But how to combine both these operations ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Agreeing with the other answerer that this is a job for `awk`, it can be done with `sed`.

`sed` offers all kind of strange commands besides the famous `s` command and there is a `e` execute command for GNU sed. After you have given all the pieces in the question, here is how to combine your ideas:

```
sed '4 e sed -n 2,4p file2.txt' file1.txt
```

Comment: This is cool! Didn't know about `e` Might consider added `;5q`: `sed '4 e sed -n "2,4p;5q" file2.txt' file1.txt`

Comment: I fear that this is a GNU extension only available in GNU sed.

Comment: So short command .Nice way to get the required output  :). I was using OSX and it was giving me error .As it dont have 'e' option . :(   `sed: 1: "4 e sed -n 2,4p file2.txt": invalid command code e`

Comment: Confirmed @LarsFischer fear, it does not work on a Mac, however you may install `gsed` with Homebrew and it works perfectly. Here's a [handy guide](https://www.topbug.net/blog/2013/04/14/install-and-use-gnu-command-line-tools-in-mac-os-x/). e.g. `brew install gnu-sed` or `brew install gnu-sed --with-default-names` if you want to replace the existing `sed` binary with `gsed`. (Or `--default-names` in older versions of `brew`)

Answer (score 1):

`ed` is an editor, and can save the file in-place:

```
ed file1.txt <<END
3a
$(sed -n 2,4p file2.txt)
.
wq
END
```

GNU awk can save in-place:

```
gawk -i inplace -v text="$(sed -n 2,4p file2.txt)" '1; NR==3 {print text}' file1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{if (FNR>=2 && FNR <=4) s=(s==""?$0:s RS $0); next} FNR==4{print s} 1' f2 f1

line 1 file 1
line 2 file 1
line 3 file 1
line 2 file 2
line 3 file 2
line 4 file 2
line 4 file 1
```

**Explanation:**

```
NR == FNR {                  # While processing the 2nd file
  if (FNR>=2 && FNR <=4)     # for line # 2 to 4
    s=(s==""?$0:s RS $0      # store each line in variable s separated by newline
  next
}
FNR==4 {                     # while processing the 1st file if line # is 4
  print s                    # print stored text from variable s
}
1                            # default action to print each line from file1
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava ..Thanks for the answer . Could you please brief how this command works ?  Also i wanted to directly get this edited into the file1 itself . So could there be a way for that (with sed -i something like that way ) ?

Comment: I've added detailed explanation in answer.

Comment: Using awk you can do: `awk 'FNR==NR{if (FNR>=2 && FNR <=4) s=(s==""?$0:s RS $0); next} FNR==4{print s} 1' f2 f1 > _tmp_ && mv _tmp_ f1`

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for AWK, but with sed something like this could work in bash:

```
sed '3r '<(sed -n '2,4p;5q' file2) file1
```

Comment: `{ sed '3q' file1; sed -n '2,4p;5q' file2; sed -n '4,$p' file1; }` works like a charm !

Comment: Above command is returning the output . But I need to know how we can make this change into the file1.txt itself ? How can we achieve this in a single line with sed command .

Comment: @andlrc Command is running fine :)   But when i try to add the -i option it is failing like below .What could be the problem ?    sed -i '3r '<(sed -n '2,4p;5q' file2.txt) file1.txt    Error message : sed: 1: "file1.txt": invalid command code f

Comment: @MathewsJose Are you on OSX? Try added `sed -i.bak ...`

Comment: Awesome @andlrc ..Yes .I was on OSX . That worked now .. :)